# Usage de "talon d'Achille"

Tags: expressions, usage, expressions-idiomatiques, grec

Bien évidement je connais le sens de cette expression figée.
Peut-on l'employer couramment pour parler de la faiblesse majeure de quelqu'un comme par exemple ci-dessous ?

> La mécanique est le talon d'Achille de cet élève.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Talon d'Achille* ne fait pas référence à n'importe quelle faiblesse. Il s'agit de la faiblesse susceptible de causer la perte de celui qui en est frappé. C'est plus proche de *vulnérabilité* que de *faiblesse*.

Dire

> La mécanique est le talon d'Achille de cet élève.

serait donc un peu exagéré si l'élève s'intéresse surtout à la philosophie par exemple.

Comment: À ma langue maternelle (grec) cette expression peut être employée pour parler d'une faiblesse majeure pas nécessairement vulnerable. En anglais aussi : https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/achilles-heel. J'ai voulu vérifier si l'on peut le faire également en français. Ta réponse contredit les deux autres, n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: Oui, ma réponse est différente. Peut-être suis-je le seul à comprendre l'expression dans le sens le plus proche du mythe qui lui a donné naissance. Cela dit, l'anglais précise bien "weakness ... that can result in failure".

Comment: Oui, je suis d'accord avec toi pour le sens le plus proche du mythe. Mais, tu as vu que même en anglais l'expression peut être employée dans un contexte moins vulnerable:-)! https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/achilles-heel : Maths has always been my Achilles heel. D'où ma question effectivement ; à savoir si l'on peut aussi le faire en français.

Comment: Dimitris, peut-être que tu comprends mal "vulnérable". Le Cambridge Dictionary indique *that can result in failure* qui correspond bien à vulnérabilité: exposé aux attaques, point faible, sans défense solide.

Comment: Exact : Un talon d'Achille est une faiblesse fatale en dépit d'une grande force générale, pouvant mener à la perte. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talon_d%27Achille

Answer (score 3):

A question précise, réponse précise: oui. Cela signifie que c'est la matière dans laquelle il a le plus de difficultés.

Answer (score 2):

« Talon d'Achille » peut, bien sûr, être utilisé et tout le monde comprendra. Néanmoins, cette expression est beaucoup moins utilisée que « point faible ».

[Googl Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=talon+d%27achile%2Cpoint+faible&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctalon%20d%27%20Achile%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoint%20faible%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Ngram n'est pas utile dans le contexte scolaire de cette réponse. « Talon d'Achille » faisant partie de la doxa académique sera plus facilement employé par les enseignants.

Comment: Une erreur dans votre orthographe donne un mauvais ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=talon+d%27Achille%2Cpoint+faible&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctalon%20d%27%20Achille%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoint%20faible%3B%2Cc0